MySQL date variable not being picked up in Airflow
I am trying to set up an Airflow DAG that contains a variable (game_union_queries_cte1) which has some SQL code in it. In this variable there are other variables (game_db, game_id and @execDate). While game_db and game_id are properly being taken into account, it is not the case for @execDate.
Here is the Airflow Python code:
import os
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_global',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='45 5 * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 6, 13),
    catchup=True,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30),
    max_active_runs=1
)

sql_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sql/test_global.sql')

with dag:
    game_id_from_db = Variable.get("game_id_from_db", deserialize_json=True)

    game_union_queries_cte1 = """
        UNION ALL
    """.join([
        f"""
        SELECT 
            DATE(s.started) AS date,
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.start_ids, ';', n), ';', -1) AS uid
        FROM {game_db}.stats_t s
        INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) AS max_number_of_players_per_table
        INNER JOIN {game_db}.stats_t_r sr ON s.id = sr.table_id
        INNER JOIN my_db.core_g_r cgr ON sr.rule_id = cgr.internal_id AND cgr.game_id = {game_id}
        WHERE s.started BETWEEN CONCAT(@execDate, ' 00:00:00') 
        AND CONCAT(@execDate, ' 23:59:59') 
        AND cgr.name IN ('RULE_1', 'RULE_2', 'RULE_3')
        GROUP BY DATE(s.started), uid
        HAVING uid != ''
        """
        for game_db, game_id in game_id_from_db.items()
    ])

    sql_test_global = MySqlOperator(
        mysql_conn_id="my_db",
        task_id='sql_test_global',
        sql=sql_file_path,
        params={
            'game_union_queries_cte1': game_union_queries_cte1
        }
    )

And here is the SQL script:
SET @execDate = '{{ execution_date.to_date_string() }}';

WITH game_union_cte AS (
    {{ params.game_union_queries_cte1 }}
)
SELECT * FROM game_union_cte;

I checked the log, and while the date is ok in the first part of the SQL code (i.e. "SET @execDate = '{{ execution_date.to_date_string() }}';"), it is not being used in the main query and only shows @execDate instead of the desired date (e.g. '2024-06-12').
Does anyone know why the date variable is not being picked up?
EDIT: as additional info, please note that I also tried replacing CONCAT(@execDate, ' 00:00:00') with CONCAT('{{{{ execution_date.to_date_string() }}}}', ' 00:00:00') but it didn't work and returned CONCAT('{{ execution_date.to_date_string() }}', ' 00:00:00') when triggered.

I struggle to understand how sql could interpret what you put in @execDate sql variable other than a string! That code could be executed only in airflow.
